# Is it possible to increase Firebase remote config quota limit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am currently reaching the maximum firebase remote config usage allowed.

The limit is 60 requests per minute. See images.

[image]

[image]

As shown in the image, the console only editing the limit between 0 and 60. Can this limit be increased at all further than 60, say by contacting the Firebase sales team?

Comment: *firebaser here* I don't *think* it is possible to increase the quota, but the best way to get a definitive answer is to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so they can check with the product engineers.

Comment: Hello, I wonder where you get this image? I'd like to check and adjust my remote config quota limits too.

Comment: @SamuelT.Chou it is in Google Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com) and there I type in "quotas" in search bar

Comment: Hi, could you help a fellow developer understand what do you mean by "60 requests per minute"? Is this the API or literally just "client fetching"? Because I'm planning to use Firebase Remote Config for an app with possible spikes of hundreds of fetches per minute; is there a limit to fetching or were you just talking about the API?